# Problem with mounts?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, unity, mount

A little while ago, I installed Unity Desktop on my pc (by way of "sudo apt install ubuntu-unity-desktop") . After removing it ("sudo apt autoremove '^unity' --purge) and rebooting to go back to Ubuntu unity, the system failed to finish the boot process, staling and finally failing on 5 entries with "Timed out waiting for device..." and "Dependency failed for...".
It seems I can still access the root file system with the "recovery" option on grub.
Is there a why I can fix this, or should I reinstall Ubuntu from scrath?.
It´s a dual boot with Windows 10, and the Ubuntu version is 22.04.

This are some pictures of the errors:

[error message 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/teJzs.jpg)
[error message 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MxV4m.jpg)
[error message 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4EFLi.jpg)

And this is the instruccions I followed:
https://www.linuxcapable.com/how-to-install-unity-desktop-environment-on-ubuntu-linux/

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you have removed some essential packages that are required for the unity desktop to work properly

You may be able to fix this :

Boot into the recovery mode from the grub menu and select the root shell option.
Mount your root file system as read-write by running this command: `mount -o remount,rw /`
Update your package lists by running this command: `sudo apt update`
Reinstall the ubuntu-unity-desktop package and its dependencies by running this command: `sudo apt install --reinstall ubuntu-unity-desktop`
Reboot your system by running this command: `reboot`
This should restore your unity desktop environment and fix the boot errors. If this does not work, you may need to reinstall Ubuntu from scratch

Comment: Is this and thunderbird same ?

Comment: That worked! 

I was able to get to desktop again. I had to also uninstall and reinstall lightdm to be able to switch back to Ubuntu unity, but you put me in the right track.

Thank you!

Comment: You're welcome also I can tell you a solution if you want to use normal gnome desktop again

Comment: Vote if it helped